# WriteToBigQuery Table ValueProvider Issue

Tags: apache-beam

I am using apache-beam==2.16.0 python sdk. Pipeline looks as below - reads files from gcp bucket, parses rows, validates them and saves to BigQuery. bq_table_name is ValueProvider argument. I am passing table name in format PROJECT:DATASET.TABLE but beam is complaining that there is no dataset by the name of PROJECT:DATASET. I am using --experiments use_beam_bq_sink flag as well.

```
pipeline \
| 'Read GCS Files' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(
    file_pattern=dq_options.files_path) \
| 'Parse Rows' >> beam.ParDo(.....) \
| "Validate Rows" >> beam.ParDo(....) \
| "Write to BQ" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
    pipeline_options.bq_table_name, 
    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
```

Comment: I found the issue. The dataset name used in the code was lowercase whereas in GCP it was uppercase.